# How to add addition actions after a Notification is triggered in SWIFT 4.0?

Tags: swift, xcode, notifications

I have a notification function that works, see below. But I want to add an additional option, for example starting a timer, or set a flag, that is triggered by the notification event. How do I do it?

```
func scheduleNotification() {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Late wake up call"

    // Configure the trigger for a 10pm wakeup.
    var dateInfo = DateComponents()
    dateInfo.hour = 22
    dateInfo.minute = 0
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: true)

    // Create the request object.
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "TimesUp", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

From example, once the notification is triggered, I want to start a timer, or set a flag = true, ...

Comment: You do need to trigger an event without the user interaction? Can you explain?

Comment: Yes. I would like to set a flag or start a timer, at the same time when the Notification triggers, without the user doing it.

Comment: There is no event will be called, without the user interaction. However you can use `willPresent` delegate function to create something like that. But it’s only works, when your app is foreground.

Comment: Thank you @Mannopson. That's unfortunate. What I really wanted is a time based Notification and, if the user ignores this notification,  set a timer to trigger another notification, for example in 5 min.  Any suggestions? Perhaps I need to look up using a timer function instead.

Comment: You can create a notification action. When this action is selected by the user, and then you can trigger another notification as you wished. But notifications are from the users side, the user can ignore it at anytime. Therefore force-notifications not recommended, instead make it optional and let the users to choose what type of notification they would like to receive.

Comment: But I want to know/keep track if the use responded to the notification. So your suggestion does not work for my case. But thanks anyhow.